# SqlParameter(string, object) can't handle constant value

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlparameter

I got a function in which I send two requests to a SQL Server database; on the second request however, I get a `SqlException` and the parameter `@mpe` is missing. If I try to set the constant value `0` in the constructor of `SqlParameter`.

```
    protected static string GetX(int mpe, string xsection, string xkey)
    {
        var xSetup = App.Current.Db.GetType<Data.CachedTypes.XSetup>(
            "where mpehotel=@mpe and xsection=@xsection and xkey=@xkey",
            new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@mpe", mpe),
            new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@xsection", xsection),
            new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@xkey", xkey));

        if (mpe > 0 && xSetup == null)
        {
            // Fallback mechanism. Always tries to get the default for all MPEs.
            xSetup = App.Current.Db.GetType<Data.CachedTypes.XSetup>(
                "where mpehotel=@mpe and xsection=@xsection and xkey=@xkey",
                new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@mpe", 0), <-- THIS FAILES!!
                new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@xsection", xsection),
                new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@xkey", xkey));
```

However, if I extract the constant value `0` to a local value `int xmpe = 0` and pass this to the constructor, the SQL query executes as expected and a result is retrieved. Can someone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because when you do this:

```
new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@mpe", 0)
```

The following constructor is used:

```
public SqlParameter(string parameterName, SqlDbType dbType)
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@mpe", SqlDbType.BigInt);
```

That's because 0 is implicitly convertable to any enum type, so this overload is preferred over this one:

```
public SqlParameter(string parameterName, object value)
```

However when you do

```
int someInt = 0; // or anything else
new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@mpe", someInt)
```

Arbitrary int is not implicitly convertible to enum (only constant 0 is), so correct overload is chosen (with `object value`). The fact that arbitrary int can also be 0 doesn't matter, because overload resolution is performed at compile time. However if you do this:

```
const int mpe = 0;
new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@mpe", mpe);
```

Then again wrong constructor is chosen, because `mpe` is known to be 0 at compile time. If you do this:

```
const int mpe = 1;
new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@mpe", mpe);
```

Then again `object value` is chosen, for the reasons above.

To force correct overload all the time, cast your 0 to object:

```
new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@mpe", (object) 0);
```

Comment: Thats it, `new SqlParameter("name", (object)0)` is working at expected behaviour.